# xargs -I {} ls {}* : cannot access no such file or directory

Tags: bash, xargs

Let's say I have a working directory named `test`. In this folder I have a number of sub-directories :

```
$ ls */*
00/0a:
file1.txt

01/0b:
file2.txt

02/0c:
file3.txt
```

Now I want to get the same result but using xargs such as this :

```
$ ls | xargs -I {} ls {}/*
ls: cannot access 00/*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 01/*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 02/*: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work using the `*`.
Is there an alternative ?

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is [usually a bad idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Using `find` is often a better alternatve

Comment: There is an answer on an other StackExchange site: https://superuser.com/questions/519008/how-to-use-wildcards-in-a-xargs-command TLDR; => `ls | xargs -I {} sh -c 'ls {}/*'`. Meanwhile, @Aserre comment is still valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why it doesn't work using the *

The filename expansion (ie. replacing `*` by a list of arguments of files) is done by the shell, so to expand `*` to the list of filenames you have to invoke the shell. Because `xargs` doens't call the shell when passing arguments, nothing is there to expand `*` to list of files. Because you do not have a file named `*` literally, `ls` exits with an error.

> Is there an alternative ?

You could:

```
# DO NOT PARSE LS.
# Do not use xargs without -d when you do not want ' " \ to be handled specially.
# Do not pass arguments right into subshell, it's as unsafe as eval.
ls | xargs -I{} sh -c 'ls {}/*'
# Not really better as it parses ls.
ls | xargs -d'\n' -n1 sh -c 'ls "$1"/*' _
```

But do not parse ls - instead generate the list depending on filename expansion:

```
# acceptable - newline separated list, properly passing arguments
printf "%s\n" * | xargs -d'\n' -n1 sh -c 'ls "$1"/*' _
# great - zero separated list, properly passing arguments
# ie. use this
printf "%s\0" * | xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'ls "$1"/*' _
```

Or instead of shell filename expansion use find with similar but different behavior:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 | xargs -d'\n' ...
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

You could also split `ls` invokation from filename expansion and do it in two passes - first run filename expansion on files, then the resulting list pass to to `ls`:

```
printf "%s\0" * | xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'printf "%s\0" "$1"/*' _ | xargs -0 ls
```

Potentially you could properly quote the list of arguments and suffix them with `/*` and then re-`eval`ulate the list for triggering the filename expansion on `*` on all arguments, this would invoke only one `ls` and one subshell so be the fastest (while the eval looks dangerous and I fear it, it seems to work fine):

```
printf "%q/*\0" * | xargs -0 sh -c 'eval ls "$@"' _
```